# Accessing bootstrap Modal Controls from CodeBehind c# web forms

Tags: c#, modal-dialog

I am using bootstrap data-id to populate the controls in modal bootstrap.

After this action, once user makes changes to the input values, on button click I want to access those values in c# Code behind and submit those values to database.

http://www.aspsnippets.com/demos/267/

The link show to use hidden field,

Here is my code so far

```
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnField" runat="server" Value=""  />
```

```
<a href="#" data-target="#my_modal" data-toggle="modal" class="myModalDialog"
    data-id="First Name" data-name="My Name">Open Modal</a>
<div class="modal fade hmodal-info" id="my_modal" tabindex="4000" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="color-line">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-header text-center">
                <h4 class="modal-title">
                    Edit  Details</h4>
                <small class="font-bold"> Name Goes here.</small>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>
                    some content</p>
                <input type="text" name="bookId" id="bookId" value="" />
                <input type="text" name="bookName" id="bookName" value="" />
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtVendorId" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>


            <div class="modal-footer">

                        <asp:Button ID="btnCallServer" runat="server" Text="Submit"  />
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Click here to submit" class="btn btn-success" ></asp:Label>
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" Value="" />
                    </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {

            $(document).on("click", ".myModalDialog", function () {
                var myBookId = $(this).data('id');

                alert($(this).data('name'));
                $(".modal-body #bookId").val(myBookId);

                var myBookName = $(this).data('name');
                $(".modal-body #bookName").val(myBookName);

                $('[id$=txtVendorId]').val(myBookName);

            });//href click


            $('#<% =Label1.ClientID %>').click(function (e) {
                var txt = "";
                txt = $('#<% =txtVendorId.ClientID %>').val();
                $("#<%=btnSubmit.ClientID%>").click();
            });


        });//documnet ready
```

```html
 <div class="modal fade hmodal-info" id="my_modal" tabindex="4000" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="color-line">
                </div>
                <div class="modal-header text-center">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">
                        Edit  Details</h4>
                    <small class="font-bold"> Name Goes here.</small>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>
                        some content</p>
                    <input type="text" name="bookId" id="bookId" value="" />
                    <input type="text" name="bookName" id="bookName" value="" />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtVendorId" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>


                <div class="modal-footer">
                            
                            <asp:Button ID="btnCallServer" runat="server" Text="Submit"  />
                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Click here to submit" class="btn btn-success" ></asp:Label>
                            <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" Value="" />
                        </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

Comment: protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { I want to access TextBox value in this event }